# ASP.Net Website - publishing doesn't move all files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, vs-web-site-project

When publishing my ASP.Net Website (not a Web Application), the publisher does not include the Web.ConnectionStrings.config file that is next to the web.config.  This is required since my web config looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Web.ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

How can I get a `File System Publish` to include files that Visual Studio seems to be ignoring.  Please note that this is a website created using [File] > [New Website] in Visual Studio, not a [File] > [New Project] ASP.Net site so `Content=Include` will not work.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. In Visual Studio: File > New > Website..
2. Create the Web.ConnectionStrings.config xml document (see ConnectionStrings.config code below).
3. In the web config link up the Web.ConnectionStrings.config file to the Web.Config file (see Web.config code below)
4. Publish the website to a folder on your file system, the Web.ConnectionStrings.config doesn't move with the rest of the files.

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="Web.ConnectionStrings.config"/>
  ..
```

Web.ConnectionStrings.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connString" connectionString="yourConnectionstringhere"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Have you looked inside of the web.config to confirm that VStudio didn't just pull your connection settings into web.config?  If it did, would that still be okay or do you really need connectionstring in a separate config file?

Comment: @tgolisch - No, it errors out, the runtime looks for the file and cannot find it.  VS doesn't transform the web config in that way unless you're setup for it: i.e: web.release.config & web.debug.config.  Actually I'm unsure if a web-site-project can transform at all, I've never tried it.  I do need the connection string in another file, they change from network to network and they contain sensitive info that cannot be checked into source control.

Comment: Does the application work as expected if you manually copy `Web.ConnectionStrings.config` file to the correct folder? I'm just curious.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing now to keep it working, I just want it to work with the publish function.

Comment: Set build action for the file to `Content`. When published it will be included along with all other content files. If you click on the *web.config* file you will also notice that it has its build action as content.

Comment: @Nkosi, Build Action does not exist for ASP.Net websites, just ASP.Net Web Applications

Comment: Ok then my bad. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you publish the website is OK.

But the name of the file into which the connectionstrings get stored must not start with the prefix `web.`, just call it `connectionstrings.config` instead.

In `web.config` you put:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
```

In the renamed file `connectionstrings.config` you place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connString" connectionString="yourConnectionstringhere"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does it not publish because it starts with web.*?  Does this have something to do with files like web.release.config?

Comment: It must have to do with the `web.` being a preserved prefix. I don't know whether it is documented, but it is something I learned the hard way.

Comment: Rule of thumb; don't start your custom config files with `web.`.

Comment: I guess not, that's pretty annoying though because I would like them to all be grouped together alphabetically, I am going to have to start calling them we. instead of web.

Comment: Any other prefix would work eg. like in `web_connectionstrings.config`. I prefer to put custom config files in a subfolder `Config`, containing ConnectionStrings.config, Log4net.config, etc. Doing so keeps them together and 
identifiable to be deployed to dev vs QA vs production.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article will help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files

Basically you edit the picture .pubxml file to tell it to include additional files during deployment